# Theorem environment overrides personal commands

Tags: math-mode, equations, environments

I have defined a \imag command to assign the value of the imaginary unit with the font \texttt. However when I call the command \imag inside a theorem environment with the plain style the font is printed with the italic font. Does anyone know of a general way to solve this problem?

The following is a minimal compilable example

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[english]{babel}     


% ----------------------------
% STANDARD PACKAGES FOR MATH
% ----------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath}            % AMS Math Package
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}             % theorem formatting 
\usepackage{bm}                 % bold math
\usepackage{physics}            
% Note: "dsfont" override \mathbb{} blackboard bold font provided by "amsfonts" 


\theoremstyle{plain} % default
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}


\newcommand{\imag}{\texttt{i}}  % imaginary number


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Duffy, Pan and Singleton (2000)]
    If $\vb{X}(t)$ is in the affine form, the discounted characteristic function defined as
    \begin{equation}
        \phi(\vb{u},\vb{X}(t),t,T) = \mathbb{E}^{\mathbb{Q}}\left[
        e^{-\int_{t}^{T} r(\vb{X}(s))\dd{s} + \imag \vb{u}^{T} \vb{X}(T)} \left|\right. \mathcal{F}_{t} 
        \right] ~ \forall \, \vb{u} \in \mathbb{C}^{d},
    \end{equation}
    with boundary condition
    \begin{equation}
        \phi(\vb{u},\vb{X}(T),T,T) = e^{\imag \vb{u}^{T} \vb{X}(T)},
    \end{equation}
    has a solution of the following form
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:AD_chf}
        \phi(\vb{u},\vb{X}(T),t,T) = e^{A(\vb{u},t,T) + \vb{B}(\vb{u},t,T)^{T} \vb{X}(t)}
    \end{equation}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: No matter how you want to type the imaginary unit, `\texttt{i}` is *not* the way to go. It switches to the *text* font and uses that in your math environment instead of the math font. If you really want the imaginary unit in typewriter font (which is an unusual convention which I cannot really see the reason for), use `\mathtt{i}` (which will probably also solve your issue).

Comment: Oh, and by the way, don’t use the `physics` package.

Comment: @Gaussler Thank you very much, it works. One question Is there any particular reason why you would advise against using the physics package? It provides very useful macros to simplify the writing of equations

Comment: The `phycics` package is very badly implemented and suggests some practices taht are not recommended (for example fence auto scaling)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want

```
\newcommand{\imag}{\mathtt{i}}
```

(assuming you ***really*** want such a nonstandard notation).

If you're short on math groups (you'll be informed about this by running the document), you can state `\normalfont\ttfamily`

```
\newcommand{\imag}{\text{\normalfont\ttfamily i}}
```

Just to comply with my personal “`physics` does many disputable things” and to suggest better typesetting:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[english]{babel}     


% ----------------------------
% STANDARD PACKAGES FOR MATH
% ----------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath}            % AMS Math Package
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}             % theorem formatting 
\usepackage{bm}                 % bold math
%\usepackage{physics}            


\theoremstyle{plain} % default
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}


\newcommand{\imag}{\mathtt{i}}  % imaginary number
\newcommand{\vb}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}% might also be \bm{#1}
\newcommand{\bC}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\bE}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\bQ}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[Duffy, Pan and Singleton (2000)]
If $\vb{X}(t)$ is in the affine form, the discounted characteristic function defined as
\begin{equation}
  \phi(\vb{u},\vb{X}(t),t,T) = \bE^{\bQ}
%  \left[
  \bigl[
    e^{-\int_{t}^{T} r(\vb{X}(s))\diff s + \imag \vb{u}^{T} \vb{X}(T)}
%  \;\middle|\;
  \bigm|
    \mathcal{F}_{t} 
%  \right]
  \bigr]
  \quad \forall \, \vb{u} \in \bC^{d},
\end{equation}
with boundary condition
\begin{equation}
  \phi(\vb{u},\vb{X}(T),T,T) = e^{\imag \vb{u}^{T} \vb{X}(T)},
\end{equation}
has a solution of the following form
\begin{equation}\label{eq:AD_chf}
  \phi(\vb{u},\vb{X}(T),t,T) = e^{A(\vb{u},t,T) + \vb{B}(\vb{u},t,T)^{T} \vb{X}(t)}
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

I kept (commented) the `\left\middle\right` commands (better than your attempt, anyway), to show that `\big` size is really enough.

I commented out `physics` and defined `\vb` to do the same. Actually `physics` provides `\vb*{x}` to use bold italic. They should be two different commands, if it's intended to use both varieties.

Also `physics` defines `\dd` in a really strange way. I don't think it's more difficult to type in

```
\diff^{3} x    \diff(\cos x)
```

instead of

```
\dd[3]{x}    \dd(\cos x)
```

[image]

Comment: Good practice aside, why does `\itshape` apparently override `\texttt`?

Comment: @Gaussler Because `\texttt` only issues `\ttfamily` and the font attributes are orthogonal.

Comment: Thank you very much @egreg works very well. For the imaginary unit notation I am using the one that was imposed by my advisor so I have to like it :)

Comment: Am I missing something here? Why `\text` in the latter example? Wouldn't `\textnormal{\ttfamily}` do the same?

Comment: @daleif In math mode, `\textnormal{...}` does `\nfss@text{\normalfont...}` and `\nfss@text` is `\text` in disguise.

Comment: @SimoPape Then it's a good thing you use a command for it, so you can change it to suit your taste for your own personal copy. 

Comment: @egreg yes of course indeed that is the goal 

Comment: @egreg sure, but again we'd like users to not use `\text` for things it is not suppose to be used for. ;-)

Comment: @daleif I suggest it just as a workaround in case the limit on math groups is hit.